# LAN adapter disconnects and can take a long time to connect to the network

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection

Pretty much summed up in the title. It is only 1 out of 3 machines on my network that has this issue. Occasionally, Windows explorer takes about 10-20 seconds to connect to my network drives. Certain programs that depend on networked drives on the affected machine will display connectivity errors. This seems to happen while I'm not in front of the machine and using it. Sleep is disabled on all machines, as is hibernation. I can trigger screensavers on all machines by pressing one hotkey on my synergy server but after about 5 minutes the affected computer will suddenly deactivate the screensaver. Power management features for the adapter are disabled but I'm not sure what other setting would cause this behavior.

Any advice is appreciated

SPECS:

- Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate Build
- AMD Athlon(tm) II X3 460 Processor
- BIOSTAR Group A880G+
- 666.7 MHz (DDR3-1333 / PC3-10600)
- PNY Verto GeForce GT 610
- RealTek Semiconductor RTL8168D/8111D PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Adapter

Answer (score 0):

What Power management features for the adapter are actually disabled ?

Have you tried disabling these features :

1-Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.

2-Allow this device to bring the computer out of standby.

If they are disabled , i highly recommend updating the adapters drivers.

Comment: "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power". = DIsabled.
"Allow this device to bring the computer out of standby"  is not present

I have manually disabled the first option to prevent the computer from ever turning off the adapter

Comment: The second feature is missing and its the one that brings the computer out of stand-by to refresh its network connectivity statue , that's why i recommended updating your adapters drivers.

Comment: The drivers are current. When you say "standby", do you mean standby mode for the computer or is there a standby mode just for the LAN adapter? Standby mode is disabled for my PC.

Comment: Yes , when the feature "Allow this device to bring the computer out of standby" is enabled , and the computer is in stand-by mode , the adapter will awake it to refresh its network statue, and this is why you see screen savers turned off ( i'm not talking about your computer , you said other machines have this issue), you might also wanna check for any installed programs that uses the network from time to time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. Only 1 machine has this issue. I can enable "Allow this device to wake the computer" but only after i check; "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", which I do not want. Between Wake on LAN, Synergy and the drives on the affected computer that my network needs access to, I didn't want the adapter to ever power down.